# How to add a system message in RetrievalQAChain LangChain (nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain, langchain-js

In my express app, I created this path to Q&A a file (test.txt) using Retrieval QA from LangChain.

I try to add the following system message to traduce the answer in every cases because in some cases the answer is not traduce.

```
app.post('/faq', async (req, res) => {
    const question = req.body.question;

    let answers = {};
    try {
        const data = await fsPromises.readFile("answers.json", "utf8");
        // answers = JSON.parse(data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('answers.json does not exist')
    }

    let response;

    if (answers[question]) {
        response = answers[question];
    } else {
        const model = new OpenAI({});
        const text = fs.readFileSync("test.txt", "utf8");
        const textSplitter = new RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter({ chunkSize: 1000 });
        const docs = await textSplitter.createDocuments([text]);

        const vectorStore = await HNSWLib.fromDocuments(docs, new OpenAIEmbeddings());

        const vectorStoreRetriever = vectorStore.asRetriever();

        const chain = RetrievalQAChain.fromLLM(model, vectorStoreRetriever);

        const systemMessage = "Answer in the same language as the question";

        response = await chain.call({
            query: question,
        });
        console.log(response);

        answers[question] = response;

        try {
            await fsPromises.writeFile("answers.json", JSON.stringify(answers, null, 2), "utf8");
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error writing json file.')
        }
    }
    res.status(200).json(response);
});
```

For information : I'm very new with LangChain for information and there is many things I don't understand yet.

I don't know where to put my sytemMessage. I tried to put it in chain.call and in the question but it nerver work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The `.json(...)` needs to have an `object` as input, but the response of the chain is just a `string`.

You can turn it into an object like this.

```
const body = { message: response };
res.status(200).json(body);
```

I think that is the best solution.

However, alternatively, if you don't want to send JSON, you could also use the `send(...)` function to simply send a `string`.

```
res.status(200).send(response);
```